# Typo3: Backend Layouts don't appear in the Page Appearance Tab

Tags: typo3

The backend layouts I create don't appear in the dropdown on a pages Appearance tab.

I tried to put them in the root and in a special folder. I also tried to put these settings in the TsConfig.ts:

```
TCEFORM.pages.backend_layout.PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID=73
TCEFORM.pages.backend_layout_next_level.PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID=73
```

... with the corresponding id's, as suggested [here (german)](http://jweiland.net/typo3/allgemeines/backendlayout-einsetzen.html). I also cleared the cache. What could be wrong?

EDIT: When I put the backend layout on the same page, where i want to use it, it works – but I want to have them in a central place.

Answer (score 1):

I usually put them into a special folder and in the root page, then I select the folder as `general record storage page` (`page properties`).

Keep in mind that your editors need read access to that folder. That means you need to assign this folder as additional mount if it is not inside their usual mount point.

Comment: sorry, i don't get it. you put the backend layouts in two places? but then they have differen id's – which would i use to connect them to a frontend layout? i don't find a setting `special record storage page` ... do you mean `general record storage page`? and where do you make this setting? at the folder, root or the place where you want to use the layout?

Comment: I ment `general record storage page` and I use this setting at the root of the website (usually the id `1`, just below the the `0` aka `root`). Then I assign the record storage to the central backend user group `view`, which is inherited by all other groups. All my layouts are in one folder.